# How to display the store url in a TWIG Message?

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I have a Drupal 8 site with the Commerce and Message modules.

In my TWIG Message I can display the title of the parent store of the product, but I cannot display the url of the parent store.

How to display the store url in a TWIG Message ?

```
  <a class="stretched-link" href="{{ message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity.value }}" title="{{ message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity.name.value }}"></a>
```

Do you have an idea ? I tested the following code but none of them work :

```
{{ message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity.value }}
{{ message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity.url }}
{{ message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity.url.value }}
{{ message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity }}
```

Comment: Try with `message.field_product_reference._entity.stores.entity.url.value` instead ?

Comment: @berramou No it doesn't work. The url is empty

Comment: okay try to install https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper, and dump the `message.field_product_reference._entity` like `{{ dump(message.field_product_reference._entity) }}` to see what gives you

Comment: @berramou I followed the module instructions, but I don't see the code appear in the window dev.s1biose.com/fr in PRODUCT

Comment: Not in the window dev, it will print the dump on the page just enable the module and clear cache also you should be connected

Comment: @berramou It also works for anonymous users, but I can't find the code to display the parent store url. In my previous comment there is the address of my site, can you look if you like? I don't know how to debug the TWIG code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally an entity doesn't have a field `url`. The url is built dynamically, but you don't have access to these methods from Twig.

So you use an entity route to build the url:

```
{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': node.id}) }}
```

See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/functions-in-twig-templates

In your case use `message.field_product_reference.entity.stores.entity.id` as route parameter. You can find out the route name by visiting a store page and look for `_route` in the output of [Devels](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) "Current route info".